# Need to condense code, code isn't dry

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this program I am working on, and it accesses another class for variable naming. Basically, it there is Organization name, how much they make per year, and whether or not they are for profit. At the end, we need to print all the info for each organization. As it stands, it is working, however, there must be a way to shorten it into a for statement.

```
out.println(Organization1.name);
out.println("$"+Organization1.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization1.profit);
out.println();
out.println(Organization2.name);
out.println("$"+Organization2.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization2.profit);
out.println();
out.println(Organization3.name);
out.println("$"+Organization3.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization3.profit);
out.println();
out.println(Organization4.name);
out.println("$"+Organization4.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization4.profit);
out.println();
out.println(Organization5.name);
out.println("$"+Organization5.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization5.profit);
out.println();
out.println(Organization6.name);
out.println("$"+Organization6.revenue);
out.println("For Profit: "+Organization6.profit)
```

Comment: Better ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, if `Organization1` etc. are all instances of the same class then have a look at your code and try to spot a pattern. You could probably write the entire thing in a few lines. And btw, `Organization1` implies a class name but it's probably some variable name in which case you should use a lower case name like `organization1`. Further, numbering the names indicates using a list or array would be better.

Comment: Put all the `Organization`s in a list (and maybe name it `organizationsList`), then do something like `for (Organization o : organizationsList) { System.out.println("Organization \"" + o.name + "\" $" + o.revenue + ", For Profit: " + o.profit); }`

Answer (score 1):

Override `Organization.toString()` and just `println(organization)`.

Comment: What if `toString()` needs to return something else? You might not want to print all that information everytime you need to print an organization.

Comment: @Thomas Then write a custom method.

Comment: Well, what if the OP's method is that custom method?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, I assume you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Organization {
  String name;
  int revenue; //guessing the type
  double profit; //guessing the type
}
```

Thus you'd probably want a list of organizations:

```
List<Organization> orgs = ...; //initialize the list of your 6 organizations here
```

Then you could write your code as this (one possible way):

```
boolean first = true;
for( Organization o : orgs ) { 
  //if it's not the first entry then print an empty line first
  if( !first) {
    out.println();
  } 

  out.println(o.name);
  out.println("$" + o.revenue);
  out.println("For Profit: " + o.profit);

  first = false;
}
```

Note that there are other ways to print that, e.g. using Java 8 streams or other utilities but I'll leave those for you to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick answer is correct.
But you should also consider that `toString()` is a debugging purpose method.
You should avoid using a specific format in.

In `Organization`, you could introduce a method to print the current instance :

```
public void print()
   out.println(name);`
   out.println("$"+revenue);`
   out.println("For Profit: "+profit);`
   out.println();`
}
```

Now you invoke the method on each one of :

```
 Organization1.print();
 Organization2.print();
 Organization3.print();
 Organization4.print();
 Organization5.print();
 Organization6.print();
```

Or better, add them in a `List` and iterate on to print each of them :

```
List<Organization> organizations = Arrays.asList(Organization1, Organization2, ...);    
organizations.stream().forEach(Organization::print);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to overwriting `toString()` consider creating a method that returns a summary of the class as a `String`:

```
    public String getSummary() {
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       sb.append(name);
       sb.append("\n$"+revenue);
       sb.append("\nFor Profit: "+profit);
       return sb.toString();
    }
```

Then, you can simply iterate over organizations to print the summary:

```
    for(Organization organization: organizationList)
        System.out.println(organization.getSummary());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Class.forName("ClassDemo") to call the class and the get the name,revenue and profit

For example inside the for loop

```
System.out.println(Class.forName("Organization"+i).name)
System.out.println(Class.forName("Organization"+i).revenue)
System.out.println(Class.forName("Organization"+i).profit)
```

Read the following doc for more information
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_forname_loader.htm

Comment: Note that although the OP's code looks like he's using 6 classes that wouldn't make much sense, since they all have the same fields etc. Hence it's more likely those are variable names. But even it he'd have 6 classes then using reflection to work around a wrong design isn't the wisest of ways, especially since the OP doesn't seem to be that proficient in Java (any probably programming in general) and telling him to use reflection would be like handing a gun to a child to open a can of Coke.

Comment: hmmm agreed !!! try to be more responsible next time

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite all the classes Organization1-6 to extend a parent class called Organization which has a method show() and the name、revenue、profit properties, and within the show() methed you can println all infomation that you want, and every object of the subclass can call this method also